# Ruby/Rails and Selenium remote configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver

So I deployed Selenium/standalone-chrome via docker to a machine in my network, and mapped port 4444 to 4444.

I can access it via my browser on http://192.168.0.40:4444.

When I try to set it up in my Ruby/Rails application though with the code below, I get this error:

```
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
from /Users/thomas/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/protocol.rb:229:in `rbuf_fill'
```

I do see a "session" being created though when I check the selenium grid webinterface...

I don't know what I need to do to get this working? I find the Selenium doc a bit confusing...

Code to try and get Selenium working:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
# I found all of these on various websites - adding them all does not change the problem.
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
# options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: 'http://192.168.0.40:4444', options:
```

I am grateful for any hints and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests there might be at timeout when your application is trying to read from the network socket, when you connect to a selenium docker container you often need to specify the desired capabilities like so:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, url: 'http://192.168.0.40:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities: caps, options: options)
```

This tells the grid which browser and version you want to execute your tests on, note that the endpoint is `/wd/hub`

If the above doesn't work, you may need to increase the timeout so the application has more time to connect:

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, url: 'http://192.168.0.40:4444/wd/hub', http_client: client, desired_capabilities: caps, options: options)
```

You should also check the docker logs if you haven't already:

```
docker logs <container_id_or_name>
```

And the network/firewall is always worth checking:

```
curl http://192.168.0.40:4444/wd/hub/status
```

This should return a JSON response with the selenium server status. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. The /wd/hub part of the URL was the problem. `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome` seems to be deprecated (and also was not needed anyway).