# Rails app and standalone selenium in the same docker network - can't access selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, selenium-webdriver

As a follow up to my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77009671/ruby-rails-and-selenium-remote-configuration), I am now trying to setup a docker-compose to "deploy" (big word - only going to a small home server here...) my rails app as well as selenium/chrome-standalone.

However, I am not sure how I can access that particular selenium instance.
Here's the relevant part of the docker compose file:

```
  //...rails and db stuff is here...
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    hostname: selenium
    container_name: "selenium"
    restart: unless-stopped
    shm_size: 2gb
    ports:
      - 4445:4444
```

(I added the hostname and container_name assuming it might help but it didn't)

I realized that port 4445 is for OUTSIDE, so trying to connect to it gave a "connection refused". Trying to connect to port 4444 gives a timeout, even if I set the timeout to 120s...

```
driver Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, url: 'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', http_client: client, options:)
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/protocol.rb:229:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)> (Net::ReadTimeout)
```

EDIT: Docker-logs of selenium/standalone:

```
2023-09-04 13:58:49,319 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium.conf" during parsing
2023-09-04 13:58:49,957 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2023-09-04 13:58:49,958 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2023-09-04 13:58:49,958 INFO supervisord started with pid 8
2023-09-04 13:58:50,999 INFO spawned: 'xvfb' with pid 10
2023-09-04 13:58:51,002 INFO spawned: 'vnc' with pid 11
2023-09-04 13:58:51,005 INFO spawned: 'novnc' with pid 12
2023-09-04 13:58:51,008 INFO spawned: 'selenium-standalone' with pid 13
2023-09-04 13:58:51,833 INFO success: xvfb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2023-09-04 13:58:51,834 INFO success: vnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2023-09-04 13:58:51,834 INFO success: novnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2023-09-04 13:58:51,834 INFO success: selenium-standalone entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
Setting up SE_NODE_GRID_URL...
Selenium Grid Standalone configuration: 

]
relax-checks = true
[node]
session-timeout = "300"
override-max-sessions = false
detect-drivers = false
drain-after-session-count = 0
max-sessions = 1
[[node.driver-configuration]]
display-name = "chrome"
stereotype = '{"browserName": "chrome", "browserVersion": "115.0", "platformName": "Linux"}'
max-sessions = 1
Starting Selenium Grid Standalone...
Tracing is disabled
14:00:18.534 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
14:00:19.101 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
14:00:43.972 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 2 available processors
14:00:46.065 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding chrome for {"browserName": "chrome","browserVersion": "115.0","platformName": "linux","se:noVncPort": 7900,"se:vncEnabled": true} 1 times
14:00:46.745 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative
14:00:47.019 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching Node b6499167-1320-4527-a966-0c5cb7495f5d (uri: http://172.22.0.3:4444) from DOWN to UP
14:00:47.020 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node b6499167-1320-4527-a966-0c5cb7495f5d at http://172.22.0.3:4444. Health check every 120s
14:00:52.011 INFO [Standalone.execute] - Started Selenium Standalone 4.11.0 (revision 040bc5406b): http://172.22.0.3:4444
14:01:57.525 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session request received by the Distributor: 
 [Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --no-sandbox]}}]
14:01:57.528 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session request received by the Distributor: 
 [Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --no-sandbox]}}]
14:01:57.596 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Unable to find a free slot for request d98fcf3f-81cd-4e64-9aa0-3d38d7fc784c. 
 Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --no-sandbox]}} 
14:01:57.716 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "8a5d64cd64365ba87694fe9702103c58","eventTime": 1693836117520603031,"eventName": "Session request received by the Distributor","attributes": {"logger": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor","request.payload": "[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --no-sandbox]}}]"}}
14:01:57.719 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - Will retry session d98fcf3f-81cd-4e64-9aa0-3d38d7fc784c
14:01:57.720 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "8a5d64cd64365ba87694fe9702103c58","eventTime": 1693836117597757993,"eventName": "exception","attributes": {"exception.message": "Will retry session d98fcf3f-81cd-4e64-9aa0-3d38d7fc784c","logger": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor","request.payload": "[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --no-sandbox]}}]"}}
14:02:40.732 WARN [SeleniumManager.lambda$runCommand$1] - The chromedriver version (115.0.5790.102) detected in PATH at /usr/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (115.0.5790.110); currently, chromedriver 115.0.5790.170 is recommended for chrome 115.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
14:03:23.262 INFO [LocalNode.newSession] - Session created by the Node. Id: 77f6d8702cd799aea7ff9ac3e3fbca47, Caps: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 115.0.5790.110, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 115.0.5790.102 (90efd4b0ad6..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:43521}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:bidiEnabled: false, se:cdp: ws://172.22.0.3:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 115.0.5790.110, se:vnc: ws://172.22.0.3:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://172.22.0.3:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
14:03:23.431 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session created by the Distributor. Id: 77f6d8702cd799aea7ff9ac3e3fbca47 
 Caps: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 115.0.5790.110, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 115.0.5790.102 (90efd4b0ad6..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:43521}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:bidiEnabled: false, se:cdp: ws://172.22.0.3:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 115.0.5790.110, se:vnc: ws://172.22.0.3:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://172.22.0.3:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
14:06:56.010 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "8a5d64cd64365ba87694fe9702103c58","eventTime": 1693836416270433852,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "selenium:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "117","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession","http.user_agent": "selenium\u002f4.8.6 (ruby linux)"}}
14:08:24.084 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "2556bff666ce426b695515c173fd1806","eventTime": 1693836504300002302,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "selenium:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "117","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession","http.user_agent": "selenium\u002f4.8.6 (ruby linux)"}}
14:08:30.999 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "532d1751abdaebf961eceed0ff1f57e8","eventTime": 1693836511216073365,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "selenium:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "117","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession","http.user_agent": "selenium\u002f4.8.6 (ruby linux)"}}
```

I am honestly not sure what is going on.

Comment: You should check the docker logs if you haven't already, also try pinging selenium from the app host

Comment: have added the docker logs. I am a bit lost :(